# How do I get a clean URL when I forward a URL?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect a URL to another site as seamlessly as possible and I am using the following in the htaccess file on the site:

> redirect /durhamchapelhill http://gds.chapelhilluumc.org/

The redirect works, but the resulting URL is messy: http://gds.chapelhilluumc.org/?/durhamchapelhill

It should be: http://gds.chapelhilluumc.org/

I could use some input on this.

Thanks

Comment: For starters try to remove the trailing slash from `http://gds.chapelhilluumc.org/` to `http://gds.chapelhilluumc.org`

Comment: / has been removed. Any more suggestions?

Comment: What is the URL you're trying? If everything else fails you can try `RewriteRule ^durhamchapelhill$ http://gds.chapelhilluumc.org [R]`

Comment: that leaves me at the page of origin: http://www.dayofservice.org/durhamchapelhill

Comment: Please try to add `RewriteBase /` below the `RewriteEngine on` directive.

Comment: Could you show me what the complete code segment should be for this, so I get things in the right place?

Comment: I've posted it as an answer, please see if it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated .htaccess contents based on comment

```
AddHandler php5-script .php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^durhamchapelhill$ http://gds.chapelhilluumc.org [R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me on this. I tried it but it doesn't work. I wonder if there is some conflict with the other code in the file. Here is the full htaccess: AddHandler php5-script .php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

redirect 301 /durhamchapelhill http://gds.chapelhilluumc.org

Comment: Immediately it looks like the first RewriteRule is matching before the redirect has a chance to match. I recommend moving the redirect rules *before* the rewrite to index.php

Comment: Your rule works perfect by itself. The problem is a conflict with the the other rewrite to index.php Thanks for the help.